# How to get latency from daily-motion player for live video

Tags: javascript, dailymotion-api

I need to get the latency of DailyMotion live video in order to synchronize  with some events (e.g. display speaker name next to the video).
I use DailyMotion player API (javascript) but didn't see anything in the documentation about that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't get this value. The latency of a live streaming fluctuate, depends of many factor and can't be calculated precisely that's why we don't communicate on a specific value. it’s usually comprised in the 20-30s range, but can be closer to 60s in some case